# Specifying 'overflow:auto' within <div> html tags

Tags: css, html, overflow

I need the "overflow:auto" to be set on few html elements.

Is there a way to embed this within the html  instead of defining the div in  ie.

```
div.scroll
{
overflow:auto;
}
```

Instead of having the above code within a   tags, Can the HTML elements have  defined.

This seems not to work.

```
<body>
<div {overflow:auto;}>
<table border="1">
<thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: overflow:auto is the default anyway isn't it? So why say it?

Comment: @Carol McKay: No, the default is `visible`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `<div style="overflow:auto;">` , hope I understood what you are asking !

Answer (score 0):

It's much better practice to use your external css stylesheet document to define your css than to apply inline css to the actual html page.

Mu suggestion would be to define a class that only contains the overflow:auto css that you want to use here and apply that class to all of the DIV elements that you want it to be used with e.g.

```
.myclassname {
    overflow:auto;
}

<div id="somedivID" class="myclassname"></div>

<div id="someotherdivID" class="myclassname"></div>
```